# Reading a .dat with 1's and 0's returns something very weird

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `.dat` file that consists of a single row in the format:

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,...]
```

When I use `read_csv("data.dat")`, it turns into:

```
[1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1.1, 0.6,...]
```

And they are all in index, thus I can't work with them.

How do I go about reading the `.dat` file so that the dataframe would be in the same format as the `.dat` file?

Image:
[How it looks like on Spyder IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y5Qj.jpg)

Comment: Did you mean `read_csv`? Please add an exact beginning of the file and the output of `read_cvs`, not "something like."

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, I meant read_csv.

The exact beginning is as I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell Pandas that you do not have the header row:

```
pd.read_csv("data.dat", header=None)
```